# Are going to give me/will give me/are giving me

Tags: idiomatic-language

A: It's your birthday soon. Do you think... you'll get some good presents?/you're going to get some good presents?

B: I already know what my mom and dad… are going to give me./will give me./are giving me.

Could someone please tell me what you think the most natural combination here would be? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not _will give me_. All the other options are natural. Maybe _you'll get_ and _are giving me_ are the most idiomatic (to me, anyway).

Comment: They are all fine but all have a slightly different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Native speaker, and I disagree with the other comment. I would use “will give me”. All options sound equally natural to my ears.

Comment: The trick here is to distinguish the subtleties and the OP doesn't want to do the work that entails.